# How to do weighted pair hierarchical clustering in R?

Tags: r, clustering, microarray

[Here](http://www.ambion.com/techlib/tn/95/954.html) is an example of hierarchical clustering of genes in the microarray data using the **weighted pair gene method** in `Spotfire`. I am not sure how to do this in `R`. In the `hclust` function, I see `ward", "single", "complete", "average", "mcquitty", "median" or "centroid"` as the methods.

Also, lets say I have performed hierarchical clustering and found groups of genes using `cuttree` method. I wanted to plot the expression of genes in a group across columns (which may represent treatment, time, etc.). And I want to do this for all the groups separately. In a way similar to the [Mfuzz](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Mfuzz.html) package's way of showing clusters.

Can any one please help me?

TIA for any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About your first question, it seems that the `mcquitty` option corresponds to WPGMA clustering, while `average` is for UPGMA. It is just by looking at the [source code](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/stats/R/hclust.R), so it is worth to double check it. But it also referred as is in the `upgma()` function from the [phangorn](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/phangorn/) package.

About your second question, I think you just have to subset your genes by the group labels found after `cutree`, and then plot expression profiles as usual.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was dumb not to look at the source code. It mentions this clearly...